# Don't get two items when using .split() function

Tags: python, split

*Okay, I really hope someone can help me with this one as I can't figure it out.
I have a list:*

```
list = ["a1 = True", "a2 = False", "a3 = True"]
```

*and then I run my code to split them:*

```
1: for answer in list:
2:     temp_list = answer.split("=")
3:     new_answer = temp_list[0].strip()
4:     list[list.index(answer)] = new_answer
```

*This part of the code actually **WORKS** and gives me a list with a1, a2 and a3 all seperated*
*The part that doesn't work is when I simply change the index in line 3 to 1:*

```
1: for answer in list:
2:     temp_list = answer.split("=")
3:     new_answer = temp_list[1].strip()
4:     list[list.index(answer)] = new_answer
```

*in this case it tells me that in line 3 I'm out of the lists range and I cannot see how that could possibly be...*
*could anyone please help as I'm slowly driving into madness because of that...?*

*P.S. don't ask why I'm not using a library instead of an array, it's because of the way I get the information into the programm from a text file which is line by line like that*

*For those Who wanted to see all of my code, here it is. book is a string variable, chapter an integer. Those two are meant to change between the books that's why they are variables. As you can see, I filter out blank lines and use "---" as a seperator between them.*

```
def answers():
    answers_file = open(book + str(chapter) + "/answers.txt")
    answers_string = "".join(answers_file.readlines())
    answers_list = answers_string.split("---")

    for answer in answers_list:
        new_answer = answer.strip("\n")
        temp_list = new_answer.split("=")
        new_answer = temp_list[0].strip()
        answers_list[answers_list.index(answer)] = new_answer

    return answers_list


def answer_key():
    answers_file = open(book + str(chapter) + "/answers.txt")
    answers_string = "".join(answers_file.readlines())
    answers_list = answers_string.split("---")
    answer_key_list = []

    for answer in answers_list:
        new_answer = answer.strip("\n")
        temp_list = new_answer.split("=")
        key = temp_list[1].strip()
        answer_key_list.append(key)

    return answer_key_list
```

*P.P.S. I found the issue and it had nothing to do with my code. It was an issue in the sample text file I made which effed up the code... just wanted you to know from the get go that I'm an idiot ;)*

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you aren't accidentally executing an older version of your script? Are you sure your `list` contains what you think it does?

Comment: Did you look at the contents of `temp_list`? Why does it contain that value?

Comment: Yeah works for me too. You are probably running the first code, which rewrites the variable `list` and then running the second code.

Comment: Please, don't use `list` as a variable: it's a built-in function.

Comment: Its usually considered a bad practice to modify a sequence (a `list` of instance) during iteration.

Comment: There is a typo: "answe" instead of "answer" in line 4. Please, copy/paste your code…

Comment: You said you read that list from a text file. You should include the code that reads the data from your file, because I suspect the problem is that you don't filter out empty lines or the final line terminator.

Comment: Okay little update peops... the issue was in my text file, not in the code itself... sorry for bothering if took up some of your time. And thanks to y'all. It's nice to know there's a good community answering quickly... was my first post. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You could append your answers in a new list. That way you would have 2 different sets which are not conflicting with each other.

```
list = ["a1 = True", "a2 = False", "a3 = True"]
new_list = []
new_list2 = []

for answer in list:
    temp_list = answer.split("=")
    new_answer = temp_list[0].strip()
    #list[list.index(answer)] = new_answer
    new_list.append(new_answer)
    
print(new_list)


for answer in list:
    temp_list = answer.split("=")
    new_answer = temp_list[1].strip()
    #list[list.index(answer)] = new_answer
    new_list2.append(new_answer)
    
print(new_list2)
```

Or you can use this below script as per my comments

```
list = ["a1 = True", "a2 = False", "a3 = True"]

print(list)

for answer in list:
    temp_list = answer.split("=")
    new_answer = temp_list[0].strip()
    list[list.index(answer)] = new_answer
    #new_list.append(new_answer)
    
print(list)
list = ["a1 = True", "a2 = False", "a3 = True"]

for answer in list:
    temp_list = answer.split("=")
    new_answer = temp_list[1].strip()
    list[list.index(answer)] = new_answer
    #new_list2.append(new_answer)
    
print(list)
```

But I see that you have updated your second function and looks like you are good.

It was a good exercise for me.

Cheers.
H

Comment: No, can't be that.. sorry I didn't specify but they are both in different functions, so completely seperate on from the other

Comment: so whats happening here is that in the first function the list is being replaced by a1, a2 and a3 and the second function when it runs it is referring to your new list which is ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'] and not ['a1 = True', 'a2 = False', 'a3 = True']. So if you run the below script it would run just fine.